# Save query results as a string vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, email

I am creating a forgot password feature for a login form.  If the users username and email match whats in the database then an email containing their password needs to be sent to their email address.  Once my select statements grabs the password I do not know how to convert that over into the body of the email.

```
cmd2.CommandText = "Select Password from tblLogin where Username = '" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "' and EmailAddress = '" & EmailAddressTextBox.Text & "'"
            pass = cmd2.ExecuteReader
            If pass.HasRows Then
                Do While pass.Read()
                    EmailMessage.Body = "Here is your password:"
                Loop
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("No rows found.")
            End If
```

The only thing I can think of doing is this:
    EmailMessage.Body = ("Here is your password: " & pass)
However I still need to figure out how I can convert pass into a string containing the query result.

Comment: Storing unencrypted passwords in a database. yummy :D

Comment: @Alex: Emailing said password, even tastier. ;)

Comment: Haha I didn't know you could encrypt them in the database, but what's wrong with emailing the password?  Don't many big websites do the same thing if you forget your password?

Comment: every "big" website i've been to that I can think of (gmail, Microsoft, steam, etc.) have a "Forgot your password?" link that emails you a link to reset your password, rather than email your actual password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EmailMessage.Body = "Here is your password: " & pass.Item(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want the one value from the DB, look at [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `ExecuteReader`.

However, as Alex commented, unencrypted passwords is really not a good idea.

Comment: Yeah I didn't even think about doing that.   Thanks for the advice.